# Magento - hide the buttons "Reset Filter" and "Search"

Tags: magento

how can I hide the buttons "Reset Filter" and "Search" in a custom module grid ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Hide filter buttons only

To only hide "Reset filter" and "Search" buttons, but keep the header filter fields, you could override `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::getMainButtonsHtml()` with:

```
public function getMainButtonsHtml()
{
    return '';
}
```

---

### Hide filter buttons and header filter fields

If you want to hide the whole filter stuff, "Reset filter", "Search" button *and* the header filter fields, you could use the `setFilterVisibility()` method of `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid`:

```
$this->setFilterVisibility(false);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) 
I make it with $this->setFilterVisibility(false);

Comment: You can also use the getMainButtonsHtml() function to add new buttons instead of the existing ones.

Answer (score 4):

You can control individual buttons with:

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->unsetChild('reset_filter_button');
    $this->unsetChild('search_button');
}
```

There is also an `export_button` child too.

Comment: works like a charm :)
make sure your grid extends: `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid`